# Is there any less or more convenient iDoc Script editor for Oracle 10g UCM?

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-ucm, idocscript

Is there any less or more convenient iDoc Script editor for Oracle 10g UCM? Please help. Open to any suggestions. Avoid suggesting notepad and so on.

Answer (score 2):

https://blogs.oracle.com/kyle/entry/comments_syntax_for_idoc_scrip

You will find a plugin for notepad++ on the page above. I've not used this  (I set up my own syntax highlighting a while back) So I can't confirm how good it is.